# Confused about the definition of internal angle of a face $F \subseteq$ polytope $G$.

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

I'm reading the book [<<High-Dimensional Data Analysis with Low-Dimensional Models:
Principles, Computation, and Applications>>](https://book-wright-ma.github.io/). In page 120, the book defines the internal angle with:

*The internal angle $\beta(F,G)$ of a face F of a
polytope $G$ is the fraction of span$(G-x)$ occupied by $G-x$, where span(·) denotes
the linear span, and $x$ is any point in relint(F).*

Meanwhile, the book illustrates the definition by:
[Figure 3.18 Internal Angles of Convex Polytopes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLJ9z.png)

I'm confused about how to get the numerical values in Figure 3.18 (i.e., $\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4}$), can somebody help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the notation G-x ?

Comment: In my opinion, $G-x$ removes element x from G. The book does not give its clear definition.